# Transpose by keeping unique values as header item

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, transpose, repeat

[image: Excel sheet to transpose]

I would like to transpose these two columns by keeping the unique values in C as header items and items in D grouped under the header groups

The header groups are transposed repeatedly instead of appearing only once.

[image]

Comment: Did you try Pivot table? You do not clarify that you want count or something under unique orgname?

Comment: Yeah thanks. I have tried pivot, but i want the values in column B under unique orgname, not count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following formula, assuming there is no **`Excel Constraints`** as per the tags posted & if i have understood correctly the required output, then the given formula should work:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F1</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a, C2:D42,
     b, TAKE(a,,1),
     c, DROP(a,,1), 
     ub, UNIQUE(b),
     DROP(IFERROR(REDUCE("",TOROW(ub),LAMBDA(x,y,
     HSTACK(x,VSTACK(y,FILTER(c,b=y))))),""),,1))
```

---

Update :

OP mentions in comment :

> *hey, tried it, but i get formula contains error.*

---

Not sure what error you are getting, but there is one more neater and cleaner approach, and easy as well using <kbd>POWER QUERY</kbd>

[image]

---

To perform the task using <kbd>POWER QUERY</kbd>, follow the steps:

---

- First convert both the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table1`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Orgname"}, {{"All", each _, type table [Orgname=text, Fullname=text]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each Table.AddIndexColumn([All],"Index",1,1)),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Custom"}),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Custom", {"Orgname", "Fullname", "Index"}, {"Orgname", "Fullname", "Index"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Expanded Custom", List.Distinct(#"Expanded Custom"[Orgname]), "Orgname", "Fullname"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"Index"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

Update as per Screenshot from OP, looks they are using Older Version, then one could try the following:

[image]

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D1</kbd>

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$42,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($C$1:C1,$A$2:$A$42),,),0)),"")
```

---

The above formula needs to fill across. Also while exiting the edit mode, you would need to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>, as these are array formulas.

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$42,AGGREGATE(15,6,
 (ROW($B$2:$B$42)-ROW($B$2)+1)/(D$1=$A$2:$A$42),ROWS(D$1:D1))),"")
```

---

The above formula needs to fill down and fill right! Also while exiting the edit mode, you would need to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>, as these are array formulas.

---

Excel can be downloaded from **[here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2ckBwkKl4zzqYlNv5P?e=jNMhhh)**

---

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use `MAKEARRAY` in such cases; I might be wrong, though it may perform slightly better than a recursive `REDUCE`/`VSTACK` set-up.

```
=LET(
    φ, A2:A20,
    γ, TOROW(UNIQUE(SORT(φ))),
    VSTACK(
        γ,
        MAKEARRAY(
            MAX(COUNTIFS(φ, γ)),
            COLUMNS(γ),
            LAMBDA(κ, λ,
                IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER(B2:B20, φ = INDEX(γ, λ)), κ), "")
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: It would be interesting to test it with dataset big enough to see the difference!

Comment: @user11222393 From what I understand these recursive `REDUCE`/`VSTACK` set-ups are quite expensive in terms of resource, though agree that it would be nice to have confirmed.

Comment: @user11222393 Try e.g. `=DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(10000),LAMBDA(rr,r,VSTACK(rr,r))),1)` to kind of prove it. You are experiencing the lag (more than 2s on my machine) already at 10K 'stacks'. imagine 100K stacks: it's unbearable i.e. it's many times more than the 'expected' 20s. Any lambda without stacking will do 1M rows in a little more than 1s.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Very interesting. And many thanks for performing the analysis.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works perfectly used in cell D1

=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$42,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($C$1:C1,$A$2:$A$42),,),0)),"")